# NameError at "" name 'pk__in' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

In django I'm trying to retrieve articles data, by checking id (which is pk) from list like this:

```
result = dbmodels.Articles.objects.filter(pk__in[123,124,125])
```

When I run this function I'm getting error

> name 'pk__in' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your filter, try:

```
result = dbmodels.Articles.objects.filter(pk__in=[123,124,125])
```

Comment: Right :) Thank alot